# Can art syle proportions have copyright?

Tags: legal, art, copyright

I like the art of a mobile game called **Battleheart**.

[image]

Is it copyright infringement if I copy **only the proportions** of his characters?
Obviously the clothes, style of the brush, and all the rest of the art will be my own style. The gameplay of the game will be different, too.

Comment: You mean you'd use the same sizes for the arms, torso, legs, head?

Comment: Yes, thats it...

Comment: IANAL. I don't think anyone would notice, and I don't think _they_'ll be able to claim that you copied that _from them_. IMHO, you should not be worried at all.

Comment: Yes, i will use only the proportions as base, the face style, the brush and the shadows will be different, also i will use two different body proportions based in that model, one for male and another for female characters, i think that at that point there is no difference between the two proportions and styles.

Comment: No one here will be able to give you a definitive answer (and if you think they do, I remind you: never believe the Internet); so to get to the bottom of it, I suggest you consult with a lawyer specialized in copyright. They will be able to give you a definitive answer.

Comment: I try to leave speculation out of my answers when possible, but those characters you have up look *so familiar*. The game in question is only available on iOS, and I have never used an iPhone in my life. I have to wonder whether this is already a case of taking creative license from previous works.

Comment: The game is also available for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, but the idea of being sued for copyright infringement based *entirely* off the proportions of a character sounds ludicrous. Bearing that in mind, your asking if you *can* be sued. The answer is most certainly *yes*.

Ultimately, you can be sued for *anything*. If that person feels confidant enough in their case to warrant the required expenditure, they are entirely within their right to do so. It may get thrown out of court on the first day, but they still have the right to take action.

You *should* be asking if there *could* be a reasonable case against you. Ultimately, as pointed out by Alexandre Vaillancort, you should consult a copyright lawyer for a more reliable response. That said, I find it highly unlikely that there would be any issue.

---

In your given example, you suggest copying the proportions of a character, while changing the general style, the brush style, and all of the equipment on the character. Such a change should look *nothing like* the original art; this would make claims of copyright infringement pretty difficult.

As a small caveat, if you openly admit to copying the original art in some way, this may provide enough grounds for a case. Unless you openly admit that you sat there and drew over the original character models, this would be very difficult to proove; I, for one, can not see anything particularly special about the proportions of the characters you provide as example. They look pretty regular.

As long as you retain *your own style*, you should be perfectly fine. Once again, you should consult a lawyer before making any legally-based decisions.

---

Note that if there *is* some concern, you have the option of simply contacting the developers. A simple email could explain the inspiration you are taking from their work, and how the resulting product would differ from their work. The developers, themselves, could directly tell you whether they would consider this a breech of copyright.

In such cases, you might even get feedback for how you could use such art in a way that the developer would consider acceptable. The developer may simply wish to have a thank you mention in the credits, or wish to provide you explicit permission to use the style, in the first place.

Comment: Tank you, i will consider using the last option, contact with the developers.

Comment: @onii-chan, for what its worth, I have already done so in order to compliment my answer with their response.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question, i am not a native english speaker, i speak spanish.